# Understanding extent used by ArcGIS Create Fishnet?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, extents, vector-grid

I am trying to create a 20 X 20m Fishnet for the island of Wallis. But I am having an issue with the output. As you can see in the image below the grid is not created and the extent is way out of the island polygon shapefile. I have done it for my own country without any issues but every time I do it for this island the fishnet does not follow the proper extent that I set out for the island.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your polygon (Wallis Island) is in geographic coordinates. A cell width/height of 20 in geographic is a *very* large grid! Which is why you're getting a single square in your fishnet flush with the minimum X and Y.

Using the [project tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000007m000000) transform your polygon to a suitable projected coordinate system to get the extent, UTM would probably be good. It looks like your polygon is probably [WGS84/UTM Zone 60 South](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-60s/) (EPSG:32760) or [WGS84/UTM Zone 1 South](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32701/) (EPSG:32701).

If you need the fishnet in geographic coordinates then project after creation to [WGS84](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/) (EPSG:4326), just beware that the grid will no longer be *square* but resemble a slightly squashed quadrilateral.